# Terraform (datadog provider) query invalid

Tags: terraform, datadog

In terraform datadog monitor I need ro create monitor which actually is composed of two queries and some basic math...

```
Divide Used Memory / Total Memory * 100 (to have in percent)
```

Have this query which fails (tried many times with some modification, but unsuccessfully):

```
resource "datadog_monitor" "app-monitor-memory-usage" {
#count = var.environment == "prod" ? 1 : 0
name    = "APP EC2 free memory"
type    = "metric alert"
query   = "avg(last_10m):system.mem.free{application_name:app, env:${var.environment}} / avg(last_10m):system.mem.total{application_name:app, env:${var.environment}} * 100 < 90"

monitor_thresholds {
    warning   = 85
    critical  = 90
}
... truncated
```

Comment: Do you have error message or does it returns wrong data?

Comment: I got an Eror whan calling ddog API: 
Error: error validating monitor from https://api.datadoghq.eu/api/v1/monitor/validate: 400 Bad Request: {"errors":["The value provided for parameter 'query' is invalid"]}

Answer (score 0):

Finally found solution form one of the other posts...
Create monitor manually in Datadog, look at the json, copy query from there.}
Right one is

```
"avg(last_10m):avg:system.mem.free{application_name:app,env:${var.environment}} / avg:system.mem.total{application_name:app,env:${var.environment}} * 100 > 90"
```

Hope it helps some one else in future.